# Does MongoDB yield lock on index page fault?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, locking, page-fault

During an update, if the part of index that needs to be updated is not in memory, will MongoDB yields the write lock during the index page fault?

The documentation mentions about yield on page faults. Does it apply to page faults in index too or only documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this does not happen for indexes during an update, aside from what the query may use to get to the document. Currently it only happens for the document(s) being updated.

There is a feature request for this, so feel free to watch and vote for [SERVER-13325](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13325)